# Limit behaviour for solutions of $y'=-(1/x) y-(1/x^3)\cos(1/x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The ODE $$y'=-\frac1x y-\frac1{x^3} \cos\left(\frac1x\right)$$ 
has as its set of solutions defined on $(-\infty,0)$ the functions 
$$y_C:(-\infty,0)\to\mathbb{R},~~~y_C(x):=\frac1x\left(C+\sin\left(\frac1x\right)\right).$$ If $C\not=0$ we see by choosing $x_k:=-\frac1{\pi k}$ that $\lim_{k\to\infty} y_c(x_k)=-\text{sign}(C)\cdot \infty$. For $C=0$ we may choose $x_k'=-\frac1{(2k+1/2)\pi}$   to get $\lim_{k\to\infty}y_0(x_k') =\lim_{k\to\infty}(-\frac1{x_k})=\infty$.

In this case ($C=0$) much more can be shown:

> *For each real $b$ there is a sequence $(b_n)$ of negative numbers tending to $0$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} y_0(b_n)=b$.*

To this aim let $z_n:=-\frac1{(n+1/2)\pi}$. Then $z_n<z_{n+1}$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} z_n=0$. Morover let $f(x):=\sin(1/x)-b x$. Obviously $f(x_{2n})=-1-b x_{2n}$ and $f(x_{2n+1})=1-b x_{2n+1}$. For large $n$ ($\vert b\cdot x_{2n}\vert<1$) this implies $f(x_{2n})<0$ and 
 $f(x_{2n+1})>0$. Thus there is some $b_n\in(x_{2n},x_{2n+1})$ such that $f(b_n)=0$, i.e., $y_0(b_n)=b$. This trivialy implies $\lim_{n\to\infty }y_0(b_n)=b$

For $\vert C\vert>1$ there is no sequence of $z_n<0$ converging to $0$ such that $y_C(z_n)$ converges to some real number since otherwise we would have $\lim_{n\to\infty} (C+\sin(1/z_n))=0$, implying $C\in[-1,1]$.

> **Question:** Given $\vert C\vert\leq 1$ what are the points $b$ with $\lim_{n\to\infty } y_C(z_n)=b$ for some sequence of negative reals $z_n$ converging to $0$?

Comment: DERIVE says ∂(1/x·(c + SIN(1/x)), x)=- COS(1/x)/x^3 - SIN(1/x)/x^2 - c/x^2 and - 1/x·(1/x·(c + SIN(1/x))) - 1/x^3·COS(1/x)=- COS(1/x)/x^3 - SIN(1/x)/x^2 - c/x^2, i.e. *it is a solution!*

Comment: Applying the integrating factor $x$ gives $$(xy(x))'=-x^{-2}\cos(x^{-1}).$$ Now $(\sin(x^{-1}))'=\cos(x^{-1})(-x^{-2})$ so that indeed $xy(x)=C+\sin(x^{-1})$, which gives exactly the expression for $y_C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $|C|<1$ the same applies as for $C=0$, since the minima of $C+\sin(1/x)$ are negative and the maxima positive, so each up and down-swing of $y_C$ covers an increasingly large interval around $0$ the closer you get with $x$ to $0$.

For $C=1$ the minima of $C+\sin(1/x)$ are exactly $0$, so that the oscillations only reach negative values, for $C=-1$ the oscillations only reach positive values.

Comment: Very nice. *Comment to the case $C=1(-1)$:* Since $x<0$ the range of oscillation probably should be reversed.